# TypeScript type that enforces only the properties of an object

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following:

```ts
const myObj = { foo: 'cat', bar: 'dog', baz: 'bird' } as const;

type MyValue = 'fish' | 'bear' | 'cow';

const myValueMap: Record<string, MyValue> = {
  [myObj.foo]: 'fish',
  [myObj.bar]: 'cow',
} as const;
```

Because `myValueMap` is declared as an object with arbitrary string keys, we don't get type-checking on the actual keys of the object (`cat` and `dog`).  I could remove the explicit declaration altogether, but then I don't enforce that the values are `MyValue`s.  (In my actual code, `MyValue` is several hundred constants strings.)

Is there a way, preferably without using a wrapper function, to enforce that values are `MyValue`s and still maintain the property type-checking?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWMC8MDeMBmIIAXDAOTACGUZANDCpQE6lkAmIA5nQ5QF6sUASyZsyMAL4xKEGKEhQA3AFgAUGqgIADgFMYAWQQA1SgBsArnuxl8QiAAtxAH3IodzZ+VAB3MivWq8tDwCPqUWqQASjqgogA80ExCYJz0hiYWOgB8WLhqMDAA2oioaAB0hCAAuqy2DnT5RSXoZYxMNV4gvrRqUjJy4ND+QA)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make use of more generics -

```
const myValueMap: Record<myObj[keyof myObj], MyValue> = {
  [myObj.foo]: 'fish',
  [myObj.bar]: 'cow',
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately that causes a compile error because myValueMap is missing key `myObj.baz`.  That was basically what I tried first.

Comment: Hrm, maybe use `Partial<myObj[keyof myObj]>` if it works?

Comment: Same issue.  And moving the `[keyof typeof myObj]` outside the `Partial` results in the key possibly being `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, that's how you can achieve what you require:

```
const myObj = { foo: 'cat', bar: 'dog', baz: 'bird' } as const;

type MyValue = 'fish' | 'bear' | 'cow';

const myObjValue = myObj["" as keyof typeof myObj];

const myMap: Partial<Record<typeof myObjValue, MyValue>> = {
  [myObj.foo]: 'fish',
  [myObj.bar]: 'cow',
} as const;
```